# Chances of winning a 25% with two events

Tags: probability

I was at a restaurant where they had a card that said I had 1/4 chance of winning something.  I had two of these cards.  I thought this was 50% chance of winning, but my friend claimed it was still 25% because each event was independent.  Who is right and why?

For [image: reference]:

Comment: If you had five of those, do you think that your chance of winning is 1.25 (probability can never be more than 1). Each card has a probability of .25 of winning something.  If there are four people only who are given this card, then the probability of winning something ofcourse would be .5

Comment: My friend argues that first logic that if you had 5 cards, will you go 1.25?  Obviously not, but that's why I'm asking because via intuition you'd think 2 cards would mean .5.

Comment: You really are *unlucky* with a probability of winning close to 45%! :)

Comment: If there are four players of the lotto, and 1 in 4 has a chance of winning, then the prob is merely additive.  It is almost like lotto , the odds are given by the number of tickets sold, the more the number of tickets sold, you prob increases by the number of tickets time the odds.  I do not see where the discrepancy is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of you is correct.  If we assume the total number of game cards offered by the restaurant is sufficiently large that the chance of winning from any particular card is 25%, and that the outcome of one card does not affect the outcome of the other, then the chance that at least one card out of two is a winner is $1 - (1- 1/4)^2 = \frac{7}{16} \approx 0.4375$.  This is because the chance that *neither* card wins is $(1 -1/4)(1 - 1/4) = 9/16$, which is the complementary event.

Comment: Is there a way to derive this answer without getting it from the complimentary?  Thank you for the simple and detailed explanation so far.

Comment: Yes, you can use the calculation described by tim in the other answer.  There are three distinct possibilities:  either zero cards win (which is what you saw), exactly one card wins, or exactly both cards win.  If you want to calculate the chance that you got at least one winning card, then you can either calculate the complement of zero wins (which is what I did), or you can calculate the sum of the last two outcomes (one win + two wins), which is what tim did.

Comment: To explain tim's answer in more detail, it should be obvious that the chance that both cards win is $(1/4)^2 = 1/16$.  Now, the chance that *exactly* one card wins is $2(1/4)(3/4) = 3/8$.  This is because if we think about the cards as being distinguishable, then either the first card wins and the second card loses, or the first card loses, and the second card wins.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!  I wasn't worried about me being wrong as much as my friend being wrong.  |=^]

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be C(1,2) * 25% * 75%  + 25% * 25% = 37.5%  + 6.25% = 43.75% the final probability.

Comment: Can you further explain this?  I'm not sure how you got those chances

Comment: yes, it contain two situations in this calculation. One is that you win 1 of 2 games, one is winning 2 of 2 games.                 For the first one: you can win the game at first time or second time, so the probability would be 25% * 75% + 75% * 25% = 37.5%  For the second one is more simple: 25% * 25% = 6.25% then we add them together to form the final result.

Comment: Ahh I see.  That makes a lot of sense  I was confused at the C(1,2) part.  It was being multiplied with 25%*75%.